# Error Parsing /Menu.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 14] Il tipo di elemento "c:if" deve essere seguito dalle specifiche di attributo ">" o "/>"

Tags: jsf

```
    <c:if test="#{utenteBean.ruolo()=="admin"}" >


        <h:form> 
            <h:commandLink action="AggiungiDvd.xhtml" value="Aggiungi Dvd "/>
        </h:form>

        <h:form> 
            <h:commandLink action="ListaDvd.xhtml" value="Lista Dvd "/>
        </h:form>

    </c:if>

    <h:form>
        <h:commandButton action="index.xhtml" value="Indietro"/>
    </h:form>

</ui:define>
```

i'm sorry but someone can help me? i don't know why this make an error inside c:if... why?!?

Comment: i don't know xD I don't undestand where is the problem!

Comment: i'm sorry but i don't understand what you mean...this is a jsf page , i am into a <ui define> wich rapresent my content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the first line

```
   <c:if test="#{utenteBean.ruolo()=="admin"}" >
```

Notice the helpful code highlighting showing you that admin is being mistaken for a keyword? You're prematurely ending the EL statement after the == because of using the double quotes. Change it to use a single quote instead:

```
   <c:if test="#{utenteBean.ruolo()=='admin'}" >
```